# What was the meaning of oʳ (o with superscript r) in 17th century?

Tags: abbreviations, seventeenth-century-english

What was the meaning of o<sup>r</sup> in Isaac Newton's time?

I am reading "Newton and the Counterfeiter" by Thomas Levenson. It contains quotes from Newton's lesser known alchemical notes. An example sentence reads "Tis the minera of Gold even as o<sup>r</sup> Magnet is y<sup>e</sup> mineral of this o<sup>r</sup> Chalkybs".

I found other abbreviations present in the book (y<sup>e</sup> = the, y<sup>t</sup> = that, w<sup>ch</sup> = which, etc) in the Wikitionary, but o<sup>r</sup> is not there. Additional googling did not help, nor did asking a native Brit.

One colleague suggested "our" as an answer but "our" appears in the next sentence in non-abbreviated form and the Wiktionary entry for "our" does not mention o<sup>r</sup>.

[image: Quotes from Newton]

---

EDIT: More examples. These are from a different book ("The Janus Faces of Genius)", but they too are Newton's alchemical notes.

[image: Newton's notes 2]

[image: Newton's notes 3]

Comment: It could be ["the ***r*** loop"](https://www.english.cam.ac.uk/ceres/ehoc/conventions.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would also say it's "our". As for why that shows up in full a few words down, all I can say is that people are inconsistent. You can see that there's a singular "the" despite the many occurrences of y<sup>e</sup> too ("the blood of this Lyon").

[Griffonage-Dot-Com](https://griffonagedotcom.wordpress.com/2018/07/01/reading-secretary-hand-and-sound-recordings-too/) analyzed some texts written "in what today’s Gregorian calendar would call 1656" which have some superscript R's:

> The superscript **r** turns up again here, but in a couple new and interesting ways.  In **executo<sup>rs</sup>** and **administrato<sup>rs</sup>**, it’s attached to a “short s.”  And in **o<sup>r</sup>**=**our**, it serves to abbreviate **ur** rather than just **r**.  Granted, it could arguably abbreviate ur in the other cases too: after all, **executors** and **administrators** would typically have been written **executours** and **administratours** in earlier times, when the convention of using a superscript **r** in such circumstances first emerged.  But when these words are written out in full elsewhere in this particular document, they don’t contain the **u**, so the writer doesn’t seem to have felt it was supposed to have one.

Comment: Perhaps there are exigent circumstances that explain his using the superscript abbreviation sometimes but not  others, such as the amount of space remaining on the line or page?

Comment: @TimR These are Newton's personal notes, so they were not polished like something meant for other people. That's not even the roughest part; lines were crossed out and stuff written in the margins. See this [photograph](https://public.websites.umich.edu/~vickik/newton.html) to get a better idea.